# ReactiveCommand IsExecuting changes to false after first emitted value

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

I created a reactive command from a cold observable. When command is invoked it changes *IsExecuting* to true and on **first emitted value** from observable back to false.

```
public class MyViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, long> FooCommand { get; }

    private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<long> _intervals;

    public long Intervals => _intervals.Value;

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        FooCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable(
            () => Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250))
            .TakeUntil(DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(2)));
        _intervals = FooCommand.ToProperty(this, vm => vm.Intervals);
    }
}
```

Shouldn't the *IsExecuting* change back to false **after** the observable completes and not on first emitted item? What am I missing here?

Note that I use binding in XAML if that somehow affects the behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct. The IsExecuting should change back when the observable completes. It's a bug.

Source:
https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/1244

Should be fixed but not in the current version (7.1.0).

Comment: Hi Daniel! I am aware that interval as such will not complete but for brevity sake I omitted the additional code like TakeUntil.

Comment: I improved on the question since it caused some confusion

Comment: Sorry I misread your question. I agree with you then. I would expect the same. So either a bug or someone can hopefully explain why it only waits for the first.

Comment: Note that this bug is fixed and will be included in the next release (hopefully this coming week). https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/pull/1251

Comment: @Kent Funny enough when I was looking through the source code I did find the test that fixes the bug, but it didn't cross my mind that it's still not released. :)